# WPF Avalon Controls Datepicker Binding

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datepicker, avalondock

I am using the Avalon DatePicker Control with MVVM pattern.
I am binding this control's  CurrentlySelectedDate to a property from my ViewModel like so:

```
<my:DatePicker x:Name="dtpBirthDate" Cursor="Hand" DatesSelectionMode="Single"   OverridesDefaultStyle="False"  CurrentlySelectedDate="{Binding Path=BirthDate}" />
```

where BirthDate is a property of type DateTime in my ViewModel class:

```
public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get { return _patient.BirthDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _patient.BirthDate)
                return;

            _patient.BirthDate = value;

            base.OnPropertyChanged("BirthDate");
        }
    }
```

Still, the change of this property does not occur when I change the value from the user interface.
Can someone explain me what I did wrong?
I am restricted to .NET 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to add the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay like so:

```
<my:DatePicker x:Name="dtpBirthDate" Cursor="Hand" DatesSelectionMode="Single"
                   OverridesDefaultStyle="False"
                   CurrentlySelectedDate="{Binding Path=BirthDate,    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"></my:DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to bind the BirthDate to the SelectedDate property instead of CurrentlySelectedDate.

Regards